# IF Function - Google Scripts

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I'm struggling to get my Script to run an IF function. Basically I want to run a script based on specific cell contents.

I would like an IF function to run based on this and have written the following code:

```
function sendemail () {


 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 

 var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Response");
 var vCodes = ss.getSheetByName("Codes") 

 var vResults = targetSheet.getRange("E2").getValues(); 
 var emailAddresses = targetSheet.getRange("B2").getValues() 

 var dataRange = vCodes.getRange(1, 1, vResults, 1).getValues();
 var subject = "Here are your Wi-Fi Codes!";
 var vLength = vCodes.getRange("C2").getValues();  

 if (vLength == "24 hours"){
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddresses, subject, dataRange);
 targetSheet.deleteRows(2);
 vCodes.deleteRows(1,vResults);
    }
}
```

If the value in C2 is "24 hours" I'd like it to send an e-mail. At the moment when I run the script there are no errors but it doesn't send any e-mail as the IF function obviously isn't running correctly.

If I edit the code to say:

```
 if (vLength == "")
```

then the e-mail sends. It doesn't seem to recognise "24 hours" as valid data to look up.

- Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So how is this code not doing what you want? Are you getting an error? Please edit your question to indicate this.

Comment: Edited! Hope it makes more sense now

Comment: Debug it and see why its not getting inside the If. You have the data, we dont.

Comment: As I said there are no errors so debugging doesn't do anything. I don't think you need the data to be able to help me, if I did I would have put it in here.

There are two tabs, one called "Response" and one called "Codes". In the sheet "Codes" I would like an e-mail to be sent out when the cell C2 says "24 hours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you get from the cell is not what you think because you are using `getValues()` with an 's' and you probably know that this method always returns an array of arrays, even when a single cell is defined as range.

You have 2 options :

1. use `getValue()` to get the string content of the cell
2. use `getValues()[0][0]` to get the first (and only) element of this array.

I would suggest the first solution as I think it's generally a good idea to use appropriate methods... `getValue()` for single cell and `getValues()` for multiple cells...
I didn't check further but I'm pretty sure it will work with this change (applies to `vResults` , `emailAddresses` and `vLength`) .

It would also be careful to ensure that `vResults` is a number since you use it to define a range... you could use `Number(vResults)` as a safety measure.